# WooCommerce: Bookings : Trying to update dB for pricing tab in products

Tags: php, arrays, database, woocommerce-bookings

When I use the backend interface to add an array to the `_wc_bookings_pricing` `meta_key` I can see it gets saved like so:

```
a:1:{i:0;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"custom";s:4:"cost";s:1:"5";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:1:"5";s:13:"base_modifier";s:0:"";s:4:"from";s:10:"2021-10-26";s:2:"to";s:10:"2021-10-27";}}
```

I've written some code to change update that value from the frontend, but I'm having a hard time getting it to format correctly.

Here's my code (not the form, just the values from the form and the php to update that value)

```
$type = isset($_POST['input_1']) ? $_POST['input_1'] : null;
$cost = isset($_POST['input_25']) ? $_POST['input_25'] : null;
$modifyer = isset($_POST['input_20']) ? $_POST['input_20'] : null;
$base_cost = isset($_POST['input_24']) ? $_POST['input_24'] : null;
$base_modifyer = isset($_POST['input_20']) ? $_POST['input_20'] : null;
$date_from = isset($_POST['input_2']) ? $_POST['input_2'] : null;
$date_to = isset($_POST['input_3']) ? $_POST['input_3'] : null;
                        
$response = array('type', $type, 'cost', $cost, 'modifyer', $modifyer, 'base_cost', $base_cost, 'base_modifyer', $base_modifyer, 'from', $date_from, 'to', $date_to);
update_field('_wc_booking_pricing', $response, 379);
```

I'm getting the right cell to update, but it's creating a new iteration for each parameter. This is what I'm getting when I use my front end form:

```
a:14:{i:0;s:4:"type";i:1;s:6:"custom";i:2;s:4:"cost";i:3;s:1:"5";i:4;s:8:"modifyer";i:5;s:1:"0";i:6;s:9:"base_cost";i:7;s:1:"0";i:8;s:13:"base_modifyer";i:9;s:1:"0";i:10;s:4:"from";i:11;s:10:"2021-10-26";i:12;s:2:"to";i:13;s:10:"2021-10-27";}
```

So I can see that I'm actually creating 14 iterations instead of just changing the values... not sure how to fix my code though. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, ended up figuring this out. First of all, I had to make a nested array, second of all I had to change the commas between the keys and the values to `=>`

So the correct `$response` array should be:

```
array (
    array ('type' => $type, 'cost' => $cost, 'modifyer' => $modifyer, 'base_cost' => $base_cost, 'base_modifyer' => $base_modifyer, 'from' => $date_from, 'to' => $date_to)
);
```